# HTML received from AJAX by Qtip2 tooltip not formatted correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, qtip2

I am trying to display formatted html that is received from a servlet response in a qTip2 tooltip within a jsp. The ajax and tooltip are working, except the text displayed in the tooltip is not formatted as I expect.

The text received from the servlet is something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>Employee1</td><td>JobName1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Employee2</td><td>JobName2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Employee3</td><td>JobName3</td></tr>
</table>
```

The items in the table are of different lengths, and they show up in the tooltip unformatted, something like this:

```
FirstName001 LastName0001  JobName0001
FirstName0000000001 LastName001  JobName0001
FirstName1 LastName0000001  JobName0001
```

In other words, it appears the text is not formatted as an HTML table.  Am I missing something in the code below to make that work?

The ajax and tooltips are fired on a 'mouseenter' action over links that have been given the class 'ajax_link'. I've confirmed the servlet is sending back html as expected.

**Ajax call in jsp**

```
 $(".ajax_link").mouseenter(function(e) {

     e.preventDefault();        //Stops link from changing the page
     var $this=$(this);         // needed to keep 'this' in scope below
     var link = $(this).attr('href');   

 $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
      url: link,
      cache: false,
      dataType : "html"

      }).done(function( html ) {                

    $this.qtip({
      content : {
         text : html
         },
      position: {
        my: 'top right',  // Position my top left...
        at: 'bottom left' // at the bottom right of...
                  },
       show: {
               ready: true,
               solo: true
              },
        hide: {
         event: 'mouseleave',
         delay: 1000,
         fixed: true
              },
         style: {
             classes: 'qtip-dark qtip-shadow'
        }
    });

  });    
});
```

Comment: It's not just table - it seems a lot of HTML is "disabled" inside the tooltip. I have been trying to figure out how to override this as well. You can see an example in my fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/o1hx267w/6/  .....the `<h1>` or `<ul>` tags won't work properly, and the `<br/>` tag was weird also. Even "removing the default styling" as it says in their documentation doesn't fix it.

Comment: http://craigsworks.com/projects/forums/showthread.php?tid=2669 Here, the creator "Craig" says that to make lists work you have to add the proper styling (list-style:, etc.). So I imagine that means for tables, you might have to do the same thing - manually add the CSS. Pretty annoying if that is the solution

Comment: I ran a quick test and added other HTML formatting, such as bold and italics tags, and those are being recognized.  I'm beginning to think it's just the table tags that are not recognized.  I'll play with it some more....thanks for the feedback.